# assign value to two variables in angular js

Tags: angularjs, variables, assign

If I have a method in my controller like:

```
var app = angular.module('App', []); 
$scope.calcoloBudget = function(davendere, offerta, budg){
   davendere = parseInt(davendere);
   offerta = parseInt(offerta);
   return budg - (offerta - davendere);       
 };
```

Can I assign the result of this method at more than one variable in the view?
like for example:

```
<div ng-if="selectedItem3.costo < off2"{{budget3=calcoloBudget(selectedItem3.costo, off2, budget2)}}</div>
```

and in another point of the view:

```
<div ng-model="budget2" ng-if="selectedItem2.costo < off1">Il tuo budget per questa busta dopo la seconda offerta è: <b>{{budget2=calcoloBudget(selectedItem2.costo, off1, budget1)}}</b> fantamilioni.</div>
```

and than can I than use this two variables? if yes which is the best way to do this?

Comment: you seem to misunderstand how expressions work.  you generally don't perform calculations within them, they are for providing binding between the value on the controller and the rendered view.

Comment: ok, probably i have some doubts...can you explane me if there is a method to do wath i'd like todo (assign function result to two variables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the curly braces binds a variable value to the scope of your controller.

for example:

In a javascript controller

```
angular.module('App', [])
.controller('testController', [
   '$scope',
   function($scope){
      $scope.testVariable = true;
      $scope.testValue = 'Hello there';
 ]};
```

In your HTML

```
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="testController">
 <h1 ng-if="testVariable">{{testValue}}</h1>
</div>
```

In your example,  you have calculations inside your expression brackets.  Although you can do simple calculations like 2+2 in those brackets,  we generally want to bind an expression to a variable.

What you are trying to do puts way to many calculations in the curlys.

I would recommend doing something like this with your question.

1) In your javascript

```
angular.module('App', [])
.controller('testController', [
   '$scope',
   function($scope){
      $scope.costOf = 0;
      $scope.costOf2 = 0;
      $scope.budget = 0;
      $scope.calcBudget = function(){
          $scope.budget = $scope.budget - ($scope.costOf - $scope.costOf2)
          return;
      }
 ]};
```

2) In your html

```
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="testController">
  <input type="number" ng-model="costOf" ng-change="calcBudget()">
  <input type="number" ng-model="costOf2" ng-change="calcBudget()">
  <h1>{{budget}}</h1>
</div>
```

I know the calculation might be off and doesn't make much sense right now as it pertains to your example, but I will study your code and try to make some sense of the calculation.  The foreign language code is confusing me.

Comment: the code is italian !! :D if you want i can post my code in english...thanks!

Comment: That would be very helpful.  I hope the english isn't confusing in any way.

Comment: no no...even if my english is terrible, i can understand enghlish. thanks!

Comment: can i post tou my full code so you can help me to solve my problem?

Comment: Sure,  are you familiar with codepen or plunker. If you post your code in one of those services,  I could help more than I could on the stack.

Comment: here my plunker code: http://plnkr.co/edit/xuTV5Ki3GpSjGQmOqOl8 the problem is thant i m not able to use the function calcoloBudget with budget0 (or budget1 ) as input...i would like to use budget0 and budget1 subsequently as input of calcoloBudget function.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to return an object instead of a string. Take a look at this example in [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/6w6ROs6naTzR62EDnRAw?p=preview)

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.returnArray = function() {
    return {
      var1: 'variable one',
      var2: 'variable two'
    }
  }

  $scope.getData = function() {
    var data = $scope.returnArray()

    $scope.var1 = data.var1
    $scope.var2 = data.var2
  }
})
```

Comment: ok thanks...this seem helpful for me...but can I do some calculation before return the array?

Comment: @PierpaoloCroce Of course you can, just do your maths before the return operator, assign the end result to a variable and pass it to the return object instead of the sample strings I have provided. Not to mention that you can directly return a **function** instead of a string...